# Exception setting ApplicationPoolPassword

Tags: powershell, web-application, 2007

Following the example in [this blog post](http://mysharepointofview.com/2009/06/create-new-web-application-with-powershell/), I am trying to create a new Web Application with PowerShell.

However, when I try the line:

```
$WebAppBuilder.ApplicationPoolPassword = "password"
```

I receive the following error:

> Exception setting "ApplicationPoolPassword": "Cannot convert the "password" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString"."

How might I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to ConvertTo-SecureString as documented [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347656.aspx).

Or you could use Get-Credential to retrieve password, e.g. something like this:

```
$credential = Get-Credential 
$credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```